# Error associated with .dll in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am new to visual studio.I keep encountering the below error when I go to debug mode in VS.

```
'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[792] something.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have tried Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and checking Microsoft Symbols Server but again the problem persists as shown below

```
 'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
    'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
    'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
    'something.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
    The program '[8592] something.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

Any help will much be appreciated.  Regards,  newbie_in

Comment: Do you have any *hard-coded* references to these files?

Comment: No,I do not have any hard coded references.

Comment: BTW are these errors or warnings? The second snippet shows that the PDB files *were* found this time. What does your code do? *Is* there a `main` method? *Do* you have any errors? How did you try to start debugging? Did you press F5?

Comment: PS why are you using VS 2010 anyway? The current version is VS 2015, which is much more standards compliant *and* there is a free Community version available

Comment: No errors,the code is building fine.This problem arises when I go to debug mode in VS and run the code.The second snippet shows the symbols loaded but the segment (source information stripped )seems to be interfering when I run the code in debug mode....and required output is not derived for this.

Answer (score 1):

The first four lines (in both cases) have nothing to do with your program.  In the first case they are saying that the debugger doesn't know anything about functions in each of the DLLs, in the second case they are saying it does.  (That can be particularly helpful when there are callbacks from DLLs to your code).

In both cases your program is running and exiting normally.

(The bit about "source information stripped" just means that Microsoft don't let debugging information with line numbers and filenames outside Microsoft.  It's harmless too.)

You probably need to put a breakpoint in your code if you want to debug it.

Comment: Thank you for the response,but is there any way to remove them and get the proper output of my code in the build window.

Comment: When you say "the proper output of my code", do you mean the output that you send to stdout etc?  If so, the problem is that it doesn't get sent to the debug output window (you can write to the debug output window with the `OutputDebugString` function - but that won't be visible in production).  If your program is a command line program it gets sent to a console which is created when you run the program under the debugger *and destroyed when your program ends*.  The normal fix to that is to put a "press return to finish" at the end of your program - or just put a breakpoint on the final line.

Comment: No,I meant the warning messages,I do not want them in the debug output window,can I suppress them somehow.

Comment: I don't think so.  Just ignore them.  The problem I was trying to address was "is there any way to get ... the proper output of my code in the build window".

Answer (score 0):

A **PDB** file is a **program database** which contains debug symbols for already compiled code. `ntdll.dll`, `kernel32.dll` and `KernelBase.dll` are Windows kernel DLLs, `msvcr100d.dll` is the Microsoft Visual 2010 (v10.0) C runtime.

Your first code block tells us, that these DLLs have no PDB file, so cannot properly be analyzed for debugging (which you *should* never need, so it's no problem). It's just a warning, no error, everything runs ok to the end with exit code 0.

The second code block found these symbols, so if you should ever send your data into kernel functions, like a callback, you can find your faults.

Comment: Thank you for the response.The problem is that even if the program exits normally,I do not get the proper output of my code in the build window.Is there any way of suppressing these warning messages?